# Build a python package only with dependencies

Tags: python, build, pip, dependencies

Is there a way to build a python package that contains only the dependencies needed by another project? The goal here is to install this module in a different project using a single `pip install` command. The dependent project installs almost 30 packages (public and private)

If such a thing is possible,

1. How should it be structured ?
2. What other files are needed apart from requirements file ?

If such a thing is not possible, what are my options ?

Comment: Have you already checked out virtual environments? They might do want you want.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: I understand `venv` is for creating virtual environments. Once a virtual environment in created, one can do `pip install <package>`. virtual environments provide better isolation for python environments. I am not really understanding why `venv` will be helpful here . 
The goal I am trying to achieve is to build a python package with ONLY the dependencies needed by another project.

Comment: I think I don't yet understand your use case. If I have multiple dependencies for a project, I would usualy just save them to a requirements.txt like `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. If you want to install them in a project, just call `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: It is a bit complicated to explain the use case without knowing the project and it's kind of confidential. There are many private plugins from different private repositories. For each plugin, a separate requirements file exist. And the build step does `pip install -r requirements.txt` for each file.  Keeping them together is causing version conflicts. 
My goal is to remove these individual `pip install` commands and replace it one `pip install <combined_package>`. Is it possible to build such a `combined_package` with only the dependencies ?

Comment: Yes, you can do this, but I don't see any benefit yet. Without knowing more about your specific use case, I would just load all the requirements.txt in one setup.py script and then execute it.
You can do similar when creating your combined_package.

Comment: maybe [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) can help you. It can resolve dependency issues and create a lock file which makes sure to install always the same things each time.

Answer (score 0):

For example when installing an offline environment you can utilize `pip download` functionality: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_download/

Basically instead of `install` you can download the package contents to a directory of your choice with

```
pip download -r requirements.txt -d <directory> SomePackage
```

then move that package to the offline deployment and install it with

```
pip install --no-index --find-links <directory>
```

Comment: Downloading and later bundling them into a package is not a feasible option as the size could grow over time.

Comment: Well then, I don't understand the special use case of your request either :) Maybe keeping it simple is the best course of action.